# Application is not working when enabled proguard in android

Tags: android, proguard

My project is working perfectly on android device and emulator.

But, If i export and taken the .apk file after enabled with proguard application getting struck, I cant install this .apk file with proguard.

My assumption, Service is not called while installing the .apk file and i did't get any error on my log.

Please kindly share your ideas.

**Here is my proguard file.**

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dontoptimize
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-libraryjars /usr/local/android-sdk/add-ons/google_apis-7_r01/libs/maps.jar

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepattributes JavascriptInterface

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    }
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
    void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String);
}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

and my ** project.properties file**

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\\tools\\proguard\\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
#proguard.config=proguard.cfg
# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:11
android.library.reference.1=../Library1
android.library.reference.2=../Library2
```

Please kindly share your ideas.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are signing this version with a release key.
If you have an older installation on your phone(with a debug key),please uninstall it first.(You can't have the same app with two different signatures on your device)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vince. I was Uninstalled the application from my device through command prompt using "adb uninstall myProject.apk". But  getting stuck when started with splash page. Now, I can able to view this error "!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!" on my log.

Answer (score 0):

FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION usually occurs when you have overflowed the Binder process. If you are not using large bitmaps on your splash page (which is the most common reason for a failed binder transaction) then it might be a [ParcelFormatException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFormatException.html), since I notice you're trying to use a Parcelable in your apk.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're keeping ADT up to date..

If you're building the release version of your application using Eclipse export, it will load Proguard settings from the file specified by the `proguard.config` property in `project.properties`.

If you are using `ant release`, it will load the Proguard settings from the file specified by the `proguard.config` property in `ant.properties`.

That being said, are you getting any kind of errors or warnings during your build? These are especially helpful when diagnosing Proguard since it's purpose is to remove classes and methods that it doesn't *think* are being used by your application.

I uninstall my apps using:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k com.*example*.*app*
```

And reinstall using:

```
adb install App-release.apk
```

If it gives an error about compatability, I discard the previous application data by excluding the `-k` switch from the uninstall command:

```
adb shell pm uninstall com.*example*.*app*
```